# HTML `select` and `input` in one line

Tags: jquery, css, html

HTML `select` and `input` in one line

I want to have `select` `option`s and `input` `submit` buttons in the same line. The following works for two `input` tags but it's not working for `input` and `select`. Please help me align these two tags in one line.

Here's my `HTML`:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div id="my_bar">
        <span>
        <input type="submit" id="my_input_submit" value="Submit">
        </span>
        <div id="my_input">
            <select name="my_name">
                <option value="5min">5-Min</option>
                <option value="1hour">Hour</option>
                <option value="1day">Day</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here's my `CSS`

```
#my_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#my_bar span {
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 0px
}

#my_input {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#my_input_submit {
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Can you put this in a fiddle? jsfiddle.net

Comment: `div` is a block level element, so without further styling `<div id="my_input">` will be on a new line. As mentioned in answers below, you probably don't need it anyway.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/cuyuzihaciqe/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update you css as follows:

```
 #my_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#my_bar span {
    height: 100%;
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 0px
}

#my_input {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
display: inline;    
}

#my_input_submit {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Here is  the working sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/z5gt4tLe/

But if you want place submit button after the select then you can see:

http://jsfiddle.net/z5gt4tLe/1/

Answer (score 4):

Try this HTML

```
<form method="POST">
    <div id="my_bar">
        <input type="submit" id="my_input_submit" value="Submit" />
        <select name="my_name">
            <option value="5min">5-Min</option>
            <option value="1hour">Hour</option>
            <option value="1day">Day</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

and this CSS:

```
    #my_bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    display:block;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
#my_input {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#my_input_submit {
    height: 100%;
}
input, select {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Basically, you're over complicating things and adding divs and IDs everywhere. Just cleaning it makes a giant difference, now you may need some styling, maybe make that humongous button smaller, or make the select bigger

Comment: I need the submit to right and fill up all the `div` element

Answer (score 0):

Assign the same class to both form elements and give them an inline style

```
<style>
#my_bar {
width: 100%;
height: 45px;
overflow: hidden;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.my_style {
display: inline-block;
}
</style>
<div id="my_bar">
<input type="submit" class="my_style" value="Submit">
<select class="my_style" name="my_name">
<option value="5min">5-Min</option>
<option value="1hour">Hour</option>
<option value="1day">Day</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

...going back to basics, how about using a simple table?

```
    <table>
    <tr><td>
          <input type="submit" id="my_input_submit" value="Submit">
    </td><td>
        <select name="my_name">
            <option value="5min">5-Min</option>
            <option value="1hour">Hour</option>
            <option value="1day">Day</option>
        </select>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
```